# The checkForWin() method in my android tic-tac-toe game keeps misplacing credits

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

The checkForWin() method in my tic-tac-toe game is supposed to check for current player and give that player credit for the win but it keeps giving the wrong player credit especially when the numOfPlayers condition holds true. Player one wins the game but player two gets credit for the win and i've checked to make sure that the checkForWin() method is called right after the text is set to the button before current player is swapped but the issue still persists. i need help please. this is not all of the code, just parts i felt were relevant.

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }
        if (numOfPlayers){

            do {
                ((Button) v).setText("X");
                checkForWin();
              player1Turn = !player1Turn;
            }
                while (player1Turn);
                ComputerPlays();

            }


        else {

            if (player1Turn) {
                ((Button) v).setText("X");
            } else {
                ((Button) v).setText("O");
            }
        }

        roundCount++;

        if (checkForWin()) {
            if (player1Turn) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (roundCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
        }

    }

    private void ComputerPlays()
    {
        Random rand;
        rand = new Random();

      if (roundCount!=9) {
          int i;
          int j;


          do {
                i = rand.nextInt( 2 );
                j = rand.nextInt(2);
              }while (!game_buttons[i][j].getText().toString().equals(""));
          game_buttons[i][j].setText("O");

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i know cause you swap playerturn after checkforwin you need use :

```
if (checkForWin()) {
        if (!player1Turn) {
            player1Wins();
        } else {
            player2Wins();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok thanks @Albanninou but your solution just reverses the problem and gives the credit to only one player no matter who wins.